# How to workaround when IntelliJ IDEA dumps files in profile and ignores junction?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, user-profiles, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij on Windows and when I create a project it dumps a whole load of files into the profile. That's ok - because maven does this too. When maven does this I move the files to another location and create a hard link using the [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) tool back to the profile directory. I've done this for IntelliJ as well. (`C:\users\username\.IdeaCI14`)

Interestingly enough, Intellij (unlike Maven) ignores the hard link and just recreates the .IdeaCI14 directory back in the profile directory

My question is: **How to workaround when IntelliJ IDEA dumps files in profile and ignores junction?**

Is this a bug?

**Assumptions**:

- Windows 7
- Using Roaming Profiles
- IntelliJ IDEA 14 Community Edition
- Dumping things in the profile on a roaming profiles configuration is bad because it blows the profile quota and blows out the profile backup space for everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - so the answer to this one was changing the location for the default place to put files.

According to [this post](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-and-ide-settings.html) you need to modify the file: `IntelliJ IDEA_home\bin\idea.properties` and uncomment the values for:

```
idea.config.path
idea.system.path
```

and set them to another location eg `c:\temp\intellij\config\` and `c:\temp\intellij\system\`.